# previewOptions doesn't seem to work with useDrag in react dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to make the preview image position relative to the pointer is fixed at top left by adding the previewOptions in my useDrag with value previewOptions:{ offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0 } but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any way i can fix this, with or without useDrag ?

```
        const Items = ({
  name, icon, preview: imageSource,
}) => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item: { name, type: 'item' },
    previewOptions: {
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
  const opacity = isDragging ? 'opacity: 0.5' : 'opacity: 1';
  return (
    <>
      <DragPreviewImage connect={preview} src={imageSource} />
      <div ref={drag} className={className} style={{ opacity }}>
       <div>
          <img src={icon} alt="img" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

What im trying to do is similar to the dragging of draw.io

[You see when i started to drag my pointer is at the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJYsp.jpg)

[But while i'm dragging the poiter will automaticly at the top left ( not depending on the start to drag position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R66G.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide your code example?

Comment: i just did, can you please check it out ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite get it what you would like to achieve. Could you append for instance some sketch with a result you would like have? ^^

Comment: What im trying to do is i want the position of the pointer relative to the preview image does not depend on the position of it when i start draging but rather fixed at top left corner, i will try to add a sketch ( sorry for my english i'm not a native speaker :v )